# Using column data as column titles in sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table with column headers like this:

```
p_id|s_id|value
```

So the table is like:

```
1|1|39
1|2|97
1|3|42
```

the first column is `p_id`, second is `s_id`, third is `value`.

There are 673 or so distinct values for `p_id`, there are about six possible values for `s_id`, and `value` is an integer.
Each (`p_id`, `s_id`) pair maps to a `value`, and there are six of these values for each `p_id` (because there are only six possible `s_id`'s).
Here are some examples:

```
(p_id, s_id, value)
(1, 1, 238), (1, 2, 489), ... (1, 6, 391),
(2, 1, 380), (2, 2, 112), ... (2, 6, 402),
. . .
(673, 1, 371), (673, 2, 239), ... (673, 6, 230)
```

So here's what I want as column headers for what I'm trying to get as output:

```
p_id 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And then the table would be populated with the "value"s.

How do I do this with SQL statements? Do I need to make a new table?

Comment: What you are looking for is called `PIVOT`, but AFAIK it's not supported by SQLLite. The closest you could do is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237068/pivot-in-sqlite)

Comment: that looks really painful! I'm just a beginner...
I suppose I'll just generate a table for each s_id, and then use those.
I'm trying to query a database to generate matrices to use in gnu octave.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Case statement will work. Try this:

```
SELECT    
    p_id, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN s_id = 1 THEN value END) AS [1], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN s_id = 2 THEN value END) AS [2], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN s_id = 3 THEN value END) AS [3], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN s_id = 4 THEN value END) AS [4],
    MIN(CASE WHEN s_id = 5 THEN value END) AS [5], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN s_id = 6 THEN value END) AS [6]
FROM        
    [TableName]
GROUP BY 
    p_id
```