# SQLITE change colum name to value from cells

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a simple database with two tables:

**dates** (`ID` - PK, `data` - text):

```
ID | data      
1  | 2013-02-03    
2  | 2012-10-06  
3  | 2014-04-22
```

and **rate** (`ID` - PK, `dataNR` - FK from dates(`ID`), `value` (range 0-6), `userNR` (from other base - it's not important):

```
ID | value | dataNR | userNR
1  | 3     | 1      | 1
2  | 5     | 2      | 1
3  | 2     | 3      | 2
```

and when I use this command:

```
SELECT rate.ID, rate.value, dates.data, rate.userNR
FROM rate
INNER JOIN date ON rate.dataNR = dates.ID
```

I believe the result would be:

```
ID | value | dataNR       | userNR
1  | 3     | 2013-02-03   | 1
2  | 5     | 2012-10-06   | 1
3  | 2     | 2014-04-22   | 2
```

but I would like to get:

```
userNr | 2013-02-03 | 2012-10-06 | 2014-04-22
 1     | 3          | 5          |
 2     |            |            | 2
```

How can i get it?
I would like to add that it will be connect with c# (component datagridView, well it maybe shows new ways to result?).

Comment: I have edited your question. Please verify that I correctly understood  your problem.  Also you list three different RDBMS (`MySQL`, `SQLite`, and `PostgreSQ`L). Which one do you actually use?

Comment: thanks, it can be in sqlite (inappcreciable) :-)

Comment: Then remove the two other tags.  Also, how large are your tables actually?

Comment: actually - 5-10 rows, in future - max 500-1000 rows for rate, but for data: 20-30 different times, look at edit :-) I added some new precision dates.

Comment: And you need a result with 500 columns? Can you do `GROUP BY` instead and then massage the data in your front end?

Comment: Are `data` values unique or do you need to total rows with the same `data` value?

Comment: no, i would get result with max 20-30 columns :)
@edit: datatime - unique

Comment: It doesn't seem that you thought it through.  Create a more realistic data set and post it with the desired result.

Comment: Ok, i'm editing now first post and add more practical example (5 min).

Comment: Have a look at [Pivot Table Hack in Sqlite3 and MySQL](http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2008/05/pivot-table-hack-in-sqlite3-and-mysql.html). This is a very static approach.  In your case it will be better to grab the data from a simple join into C# array and do the pivoting on front-end side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pivot in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237068/pivot-in-sqlite)