# SQLite - Complex Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is what I want to get.

```
Art|CANTIDAD1|CANTIDAD2|CANTIDAD1CARGA1 |CANTIDAD2CARGA1 |CANTIDAD1CARGA2 | CANTIDAD2CARGA2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001|    7    |    0    |       4        |        0       |        3       |        0
002|    0    |    2    |       0        |        1       |        0       |        1
003|    2    |    0    |       2        |        0       |        0       |        0
004|    3    |    0    |       1        |        0       |        2       |        0
005|    2    |    0    |       0        |        0       |        2       |        0
006|    0    |    1    |       0        |        0       |        0       |        1
```

I get CANTIDAD1 and CANTIDAD2 doing this query. It is the result of the sum of the amounts corresponding to the "where"

```
SELECT 
    SUM(D.NCANTIDAD1) AS NTOTCANTIDAD1, 
    SUM(D.NCANTIDAD2) AS NTOTCANTIDAD2 
FROM 
    CABPEDIDOS C, 
    DETPEDIDOS D, 
    ARTICULOS A 
WHERE 
    C.DFECHAALBARAN IS NULL 
    AND C.CSERIE = D.CSERIE 
    AND C.NPEDIDO = D.NPEDIDO 
    AND D.NFABRICANTE = A.NFABRICANTE 
    AND D.CARTICULO = A.CARTICULO 
GROUP BY 
    D.NFABRICANTE, D.CARTICULO, A.CNOMBRE
```

`CANTIDAD1CARGA1`, `CANTIDAD2CARGA1` are quantities that are in the database (d.cantidad1, d,cantidad2 are the real names, I have to sum all of them to get CANTIDAD1 and CANTIDAD2), but I need to get the quantities corresponding to the respective `C.CARGA`:

```
(CANTIDAD1 = CANTIDAD1CARGA1 + CANTIDAD1CARGA2)
```

How can I get these values?

** `C.NCARGA` can have more than one value, I need to get all `CANTIDAD1CARGA'x'` and `CANTIDAD2CARGA'x'`

```
I don't care if I have to use two querys, 
- one for CANTIDAD1 and CANTIDAD2
- other for CANTIDAD1CARGA1, CANTIDAD2CARGA1, CANTIDAD1CARGA2... etc
```

Comment: It looks like what you want is a type of Pivot, which unfortunately doesn't seem to be supported in SqlLite. There are some [ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1237068/314291)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling I'm not really understanding the question, but it seems like you just need:

```
SELECT CANTIDAD1CARGA1 + CANTIDAD1CARGA2 AS CANTIDAD1,
       CANTIDAD2CARGA1 + CANTIDAD2CARGA2 AS CANTIDAD2,
       CANTIDAD1CARGA1, CANTIDAD2CARGA1, CANTIDAD1CARGA2, CANTIDAD2CARGA2
FROM ...
```

Comment: I've edited the first post. I haven't got "CANTIDAD1CARGA1 or CANTIDAD2CARGA1", it's a bit hard to explain, I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't understand. Please update your question to show all the input tables.

Comment: Best would be to make a sqlfiddle with some sample data and your attempted solution.