# SQLite Excel style Pivot table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite as my database in my C++ application. I have a table similar to one given below

```
Day | PartyA | PartyB | Amount
--------------------------------
1   |    X   |   Y    | 25
1   |    X   |   K    | 10
1   |    Y   |   M    | 30
1   |    Z   |   L    | 20
2   |    X   |   Y    | 10
2   |    X   |   K    | 30
2   |    Y   |   M    | 50
2   |    Z   |   L    | 5
3   |    X   |   K    | 60
3   |    Y   |   M    | 15
```

and I want to get something like the table below. This is similar to MS Excel pivot table; the final table has unique PartyA - PartyB pairs and a column named TotalAmount has the summation of Amount values given in the previous table.

```
PartyA | PartyB | TotalAmount
--------------------------------
   X   |   Y    | 35
   X   |   K    | 100
   Y   |   M    | 95
   Z   |   L    | 25
```

Although, the C/C++ API interface allows to implement this, I want to do it by using SQL queries.

Your assistance will be much appreciated on the matter.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by PartyA and PartyB and then take the sum of Amount for each group. Use the following query:

```
SELECT PartyA, PartyB, SUM(Amount) TotalAmount FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY PartyA, PartyB;
```

This groups the matching pair of PartyA and PartyB before applying the sum function.

[SQLFiddle demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/284bb/1)

**COMMENT:**

You have mentioned 'pivot' in your title. But as you can see from the above query, you don't need to use a pivot for your requirement. Also, SQLite doesn't support the pivot function. But a workaround for pivot is possible, [as shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237068/pivot-in-sqlite). Just added here for your reading.

Comment: If truth to be told, not sure about the Pivot concept in SQL, that's why I explicitly stated Excel style in my post, as this is the only pivot I know :)

Comment: You should most definitely read up on pivot then. It is quite a handy thing and you might come across some use cases in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be sql way of doing this

```
select PartyA,PartyB, sum(Amount) as TotalAmount from <giventable> 
group by PartyA, PartyB
```

Also refer [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm) for more