# SQLite pivot producing alternate NULLS

Tags: sqlite, pivot

I'm having a problem with my SQLite pivot code, mainly taken from McPeppr's answer here: [Pivot in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237068/pivot-in-sqlite)

Creating my temp table:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT      band, 
    p.name, 
    status, 
    strftime('%Y-%m', time_start) AS Month,
    AVG(time) AS Avg
FROM person p

JOIN action a ON p.person_id = a.person_id
JOIN log l ON p.log_id = l.log_id

WHERE p.person = 'Joe' AND opps = '2'

GROUP BY band, Month, status, strftime('%Y-%m', time_stamp_start)

ORDER BY Month, CASE status
                WHEN 'one' THEN 0
                WHEN 'two' THEN 1
                WHEN 'three' THEN 2
                WHEN 'four' THEN 3
            END
),
```

t1 looks like:

```
  band |  name  | status |   month   |     AVG 
 ------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------
    1  |  Joe   |  one   |  2018-01  |     3.33      
    2  |  Joe   |  one   |  2018-01  |     4.11
    1  |  Joe   |  two   |  2018-02  |     2.55      
    2  |  Joe   |  two   |  2018-02  |     3.45 
  ..........
```

When I try pivot in a select I get:

```
Select band, Month,
case when status = 'one' then response_avg end as One,
case when status = 'two' then response_avg end as Two,
...,
from t1
```

This:

```
  band |   month    |  One  |  Two  
 ------+------------+-------+---------
    1  |  2018-01   |  3.41 |  NULL    
    2  |  2018-01   |  3.55 |  NULL
    1  |  2018-01   |  NULL |  2.55     
    2  |  2018-01   |  NULL |  4.61
    1  |  2018-02   |  1.55 |  NULL    
    2  |  2018-02   |  2.43 |  NULL
    1  |  2018-02   |  NULL |  4.33     
    2  |  2018-02   |  NULL |  3.44
```

Whereas I want

```
  band |   month    |  One  |  Two  
 ------+------------+-------+---------
    1  |  2018-01   |  3.41 |  2.55    
    2  |  2018-01   |  3.55 |  4.61
    1  |  2018-02   |  1.55 |  2.55     
    2  |  2018-02   |  2.43 |  4.61
```

I understand that the status column is causing this but can't figure out how to fix it.

I've tried a good few methods (multiple temp tables, sub-selects to remove the "status" due to default grouping) from different questions I found on here but keep ending up with the same result. Any help appreciated

Comment: With T1 as ... is not a temp table but a CTE https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: Does this help me fix my pivot? Honest question cause I don't really understand the linked reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick when you are using CASE/WHEN is to use aggregative functions like MAX and then group by all the non-aggragate columns :

```
SELECT 
   band,
   Month,
   MAX(CASE 
          when status = 'one' then response_avg
      END) as One,
   MAX(CASE 
          when status = 'two' then response_avg
      END) as Two
FROM t1
GROUP BY band,
   Month
```

Comment: Ah I see now! Should have figured that out myself. Thanks for the help