# SQLITE combine select result set

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
|-----------------------------|
|someText | Date | someInteger|
|-----------------------------|
```

What i want is to select a query like this:

```
|-----------------------------------|
|someText | Jan | Feb | March | ... |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Basicaly i want to summ all the someInteger grouped by someText for each single month, aka

```
Select Sum(someInteger) From TABLE
Where Date = [month]
GroupBy someText
```

...and then, if possible, i would like to combine all the 12 queries of this into one resulting table for ease of use and possibly some optimisation.

Comment: Sample data as create table and insert statements for easy importing and the expected results of that data would be useful.

Comment: Maybe you can relate to pivot system : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237068/pivot-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation (assuming that all the dates are in the same year):

```
select 
  someText,
  sum(case when strftime('%m', date) = '01' then someInteger end) Jan,
  sum(case when strftime('%m', date) = '02' then someInteger end) Feb,
  sum(case when strftime('%m', date) = '03' then someInteger end) Mar,
  ...................................................................
from tablename
group by someText
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fVTkGvxaWjB4pbBMPrPCDz/1).

Comment: Any idea why strftime may return empty string?

Comment: The format of the date must be `yyyy-mm-dd`. If not you get null.

Answer (score 0):

How about `group by`?

```
Select strftime('%y-%m', date) as yyyymm,
       sum(someInteger)
from t
group by strftime('%y-%m', date);
```