# Make a query making groups on the same result row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables. Like this.

```
select * from extrafieldvalues;
+----------------------------+
| id | value | type | idItem |
+----------------------------+
| 1  | 100   | 1    | 10     |
| 2  | 150   | 2    | 10     |
| 3  | 101   | 1    | 11     |
| 4  | 90    | 2    | 11     |
+----------------------------+
```

```
select * from items
+------------+
| id  | name |
+------------+
| 10  | foo  |
| 11  | bar  |
+------------+
```

I need to make a query and get something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| idItem  | valtype1 | valtype2 | name |
+--------------------------------------+
| 10      | 100      | 150      | foo  |
| 11      | 101      | 90       | bar  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

The quantity of types of extra field values is variable, but every item ALWAYS uses every extra field.

Comment: It's called a pivot query. StackOverflow has many examples of thi, one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237068/pivot-in-sqlite - see haridev's answer

Comment: As I told, the "extra fields" are variable, can be 2, 3, ... , n

Comment: You'll need to generate the query programmatically in your front end then, after doing a select distinct for all the relevant values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only two fields, then `left join` is an option for this:

```
select i.*, efv1.value as value_1, efv2.value as value_2
from items i left join
     extrafieldvalues efv1
     on efv1.iditem = i.id and
        efv1.type = 1 left join
     extrafieldvalues efv2
     on efv1.iditem = i.id and
        efv1.type = 2 ;
```

In terms of performance, two joins are probably faster than an aggregation -- and it makes it easier to bring in more columns from `items`.  One the other hand, conditional aggregation generalizes more easily and the performance changes by little as more columns from `extrafieldvalues` are added to the `select`.

Comment: I'm making this (I'm generating the query programatically)

`select itemes.*, valor0.datoValor as Voltaje, valor1.datoValor as Foto, valor2.datoValor as Volumen, valor3.datoValor as Marca, valor4.datoValor as Color from itemes left join valores valor0 on valor0.idItem=itemes.idItem left join valores valor1 on valor1.idItem=itemes.idItem left join valores valor2 on valor2.idItem=itemes.idItem left join valores valor3 on valor3.idItem=itemes.idItem left join valores valor4 on valor4.idItem=itemes.idItem`

But I'm getting results of more than 60M of rows (and ITEMES table has 440)

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select iditem, 
       max(case when type=1 then value end) as valtype1,
       max(case when type=2 then value end) as valtype2,name
from extrafieldvalues a inner join items b on a.iditem=b.id
group by iditem,name
```

Comment: This is great. Why did you use max with it? Also, without max it does not work. Why it is like this?

Comment: @ArchDesai, you can use min/sum also, the point is you need to use aggregate function , btw, if it helped u please consider it to mark as accepted